# Duplicate entry while using updateOrCreate()

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using (latest) Lumen, which could be the culprit to my error.

When I'm using updateOrCreate():

```
            User::updateOrCreate(
            ['username'     => $user->username],
            [
                'email'         => $user->email,
                'password'      => $user->password,
                'foreign_id'    => $user->foreign_id,                
                'client_id'     => $user->client_id,
                'status'        => $user->active,
                'user_level'    => (integer) $user->user_level
            ]
        );
```

on one of my models, I get mysql error:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'user@name.com' for key 'users_username_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`,
```

because it tries to insert duplicate value for one of my unique columns (username).

So, function itself exists, I dont get any errors, and it works for first inserts, but once it reaches functionality of checking if DB entry exists and needs only to update it, it still wants to create new entry, but with duplicated value.

Laravel itself has updateOrCreate(): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts in its Eloquent. Is Eloquent in Lumen somehow crippled on this function?

When looking through the code of Laravel or Lumen, I cannot find this function implemented, the closest is updateOrFail()...

Comment: I don't think that problem is in App side. Most likely some other user has the same email. As user->email has to be unique to each user then you can't insert user with already reserved email. Also you can't change email to be any of already reserved ones if you are updating existing user

Comment: I have problems with unique usernames, I didnt limit email as unique column. But that aside: my understanding is, if there is a user with same username, the existing entry should be updated with new data, not trying to insert new row into DB..

Answer (score 5):

```
User::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'username'     => $user->username,
            'foreign_id'    => $user->foreign_id
        ],

        [
            'email'         => $user->email,
            'password'      => $user->password,                                
            'client_id'     => $user->client_id,
            'status'        => $user->active,
            'user_level'    => (integer) $user->user_level
        ])
```

// first array must contains all the primary/composite keys which makes the it a unique records

Comment: Hmm, this could be problematic in scenarios, where foreign_id is not mandatory. foreign_id is only used when I'm doing sync from old database while foreign_id is empty if user is created using new system. Username must be unique tho in both cases..

Comment: I had a similar situation with a numeric value on an int column,
it seems that some values were biginteger type and that was the cause of the bug

Comment: Does it need to contain ALL those keys, or at least one that is unique? For example, I have a table with an `id` PK, and a different natural key that's unique (e.g. an external payment processor line item ID). When I call `updateOrCreate()`, I cannot pass the `id`, but I want to pass the external ID and have the operation decay into UPDATE if that particular constraint is violated.